# exporting chat history in the new 8.x version of skype

Tags: macos, skype, export

Previous pre v8 versions of skype stored the chat history in an sqlite database called main.db.

However, the newest version of skype (8.16.0.4 at the time of this message) apparently does something different.

Exporting the data will only allow you to export message from before the v8 upgrade and I am unable to find where the messages from v8 onwards are stored or how to export them.

Any help or advice in finding where messages are now stored would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What a really bad move.  Here was Microsoft, *opening up* and then they do this privacy nightmare lock down.  I was starting to think I might like them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jomel_G on 1/16/2018 9:19:14 PM](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_windesk-skype_messms-skype_instamessms/chat-history-on-new-skype/fd7677a6-1ffa-447d-9fdb-c07805145c4b):

> In the classic version, we store your chat database to a specialized
>   file in the Skype roaming folder that's why it's possible to recover
>   your conversations if you're able to back that file up. However, it is
>   not possible with the new Skype.
>
> Not all conversations from the classic version will be carried over to
>   the new Skype. But moving forward, your conversations will be saved
>   for 2 years in the cloud.
>
> Regarding the issue when you attempt to install the classic version,
>   you might be clicking the wrong selection from the drop-down of our
>   Downloads page. Below are the steps to download the classic version of
>   Skype:
>
> 1. Go to https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/
> 2. From the drop-down selection, select **Get classic Skype**.

Comment: that's a bit shocking that skpe now stores messages "in the cloud" without giving the user a warning or even a choice.  thanks for the info.  much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, the "classic version of Skype" is just about to stop working.  For over a month now, it has been telling me that the LATEST legacy version will "soon stop working".  It is now September 12th, 2018 and still working--for now.  We NEED to have a better answer than to simply "copy and paste" from a web page.  I WANT the REAL database, not just the data, which is very incomplete.

Comment: ok so how to find them in the cloud and save all to a file ?  And I don't mean one-by-one using repeated Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C, scroll, taking weeks worth of time.  They are my conversations, I need them

Comment: It not work now. Really need some solution.

Answer (score 3):

It is a pain that the local main.db is not used anymore; searching with Skyperious was bliss.

Now you need to visit https://secure.skype.com/en/data-export and request an archive of your stuff...

Comment: Yes.   not exactly what I was looking for.  But it is the closest thing we will get.  Takes about 30-90 minutes from the request time for the archive file to be ready for download once you request it.   Not sure why you cannot initiate this request within Skype client itself or the [web client](https://web.skype.com)

Answer (score 0):

There is now a way to export the chat for skype 8.
You have to follow the instructions here:
https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34894/how-do-i-export-my-skype-files-and-chat-history
The resulting archive you download contains a folder with all files and shared media and a single json file that contains everything, from your addressbook to the groups and all the messages within.

Answer (score -3):

To export the Skypechat from Skype 8.x simply copy-paste the chat into a textfile. I assume you get Unix-Lineendings.

Comment: Did you even try that ?  That doesn't work. You can maybe copy a few messages that way -- what you see on the screen -- that's it.  We're talking Skype8 *history* here, not just a few chats.  Please give serious answers