# Save full Skype chat history including photos

Tags: backup, skype, skype-for-windows-10

I am moving to a new computer and Skype account and would like to make a backup of a specific chat in the old account including the files shared in the conversation. The files that Skype saves in the cloud are only of the last 30 days, but when I look in Skype for windows backwards, even years back, I can still access and see the photos, so I assume they are saved locally somewhere. I would like to save all of those photos/files but can't figure out where Skype saves it. Skype chat export does not save the files, only the chat itself.

Would appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Skype v7 and lower the local database was in `%AppData%\Skype\[skype username]\main.db` A program called [Skyperious](https://suurjaak.github.io/Skyperious/index.html) or [SkyHistory](https://skyhistory.scand.com/download/) could read this database

The new skype v8 the complete database is stored in the cloud, not locally.  You may request a copy of the history here:
https://go.skype.com/export

Unclear about exactly how much history is stored, but some estimates say previous 2 years.

Takes about 30-90 minutes for the tar ball to be ready.  Just refresh the request page to see if the "Pending" becomes "Download".  Or also the notification will appear in your skype client notification section with the download link.

Don't ask why Skype developer didn't just put this link (to initiate the database history request) in the desktop/[web app](https://web.skype.com).

[answer for mac](https://superuser.com/a/1490235/140631) is the same

---

[additional reference](https://github.com/suurjaak/Skyperious/issues/74#issuecomment-517901740) for skyperious workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the path below by press “Win+R” to open RUN.

Skype profile data (including contacts, chat & voice history, etc...) is saved in %AppData%\Skype\ which will typically be c:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Skype\.